# unable to create PHAR archive

Tags: php, phar

im a PHP newbie . .

i've tried to make a PHAR of my project.

my project include 5 directories and multiply classes within each dir.

I've followed this tutorial

[Phar – PHP archiving practice](http://www.script-tutorials.com/phar-php-archiving-practice/)

and i did the following:

to my main index.php i added this lines:

```
$sLibraryPath = 'lib/myPhar.phar';

// we will build library in case if it not exist
if (! file_exists($sLibraryPath)) {
   ini_set("phar.readonly", 0); // Could be done in php.ini

   $oPhar = new Phar($sLibraryPath); // creating new Phar
   $oPhar->setDefaultStub('index.php', 'classes/index.php'); // pointing main file which require all classes
   $oPhar->buildFromDirectory('classes/'); // creating our library using whole directory

   $oPhar->compress(Phar::GZ); // plus - compressing it into gzip
```

}

and i created a new folder called classes , and created a index.php file within it, and there i included all my project classes.

i've chmod 777 the following directories: lib, HelloWorld , HelloWorld/index.php  ,

and changed the phar.readonly. (phar.readonly = 0)

still i get this message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'unable to create temporary file' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/HelloWorld/index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/HelloWorld/index.php(10): Phar->setDefaultStub('index.php', 'classes/index.p...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/HelloWorld/index.php on line 10
```

i havent found any helpful info what to do with it, and i will glad for your help.

(if there is a better way to create PHAR it will be fine)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the point, but check this link [Bug #63112 PharException when compiling](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63112)
May be you have the same trouble with temp directory?

Comment: yea i saw this, but i don't really know what to do with his answer:

"I did, but this was under Parallels with an expandable disk.  I've created a fixed disk and mounted it on /tmp and the compile now completes successfully.

Comment: @user2515512 he is running mac os, so there is some magic with Parallels :)
You can use this article to check how your PHP interact with tmp directory [sys_get_temp_dir](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use the PHP2Phar package to create your Phar file from PHP files.

Link:
https://github.com/00F100/php2phar

Usage:

```
$ php php2phar.phar --dir-source <path/to/dir> --index-file </path/to/index.php> --output-file <path/to/file.phar>
```

Comment: Please *disclose in your answer* that this is your own project. Can I ask you to read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) I removed the other copies of this answer.